# Changing DataFrame data type to a float, but some data can't be converted

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe with string data type. Most of the data can be converted to a integer or float. However, some rows can't be converted.

Dataframe as illustrated below:

| A |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| - |

Note that although it's a number, it's still in a string format. So, I apply this code:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
```

However, when it comes to the fourth row, it will show this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

I just want to skip the conversion for rows that cannot be converted like that fourth row on the table. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If there are not missing values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric values to `NaN`, so then remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['A'])
```

If possible missing values chain mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` - non missing values after converting OR missing values before converting in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
orig = df['A'].isna()
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')

df = df[df['A'].notna() | orig]
```

Comment: That works well, thank you. Just curious, what does that 'coerce' do? and what does ```df[df['A'].notna() | orig]``` do?

Comment: @el-cheapo - Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or just do regex with `astype`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('[\d|\.]')].astype(float)
     A
0  2.0
1  3.0
2  1.0
>>>
```